# centering a uipopover in iPad

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I would like to create a new keyboard for the iPad.

I have designed a view that has the keys and all the underlying work to fill in a textbox as the user presses the keys, and passes the value back to the calling routine when the user presses the return button.

This all works ok.

Now - I want to create this view as a popover.

I have the basic operations complete (pops up and is dismissed)

But now I need some fine tuning help.

Here are my questions...

1) How do I create a popover window centered on the screen without a UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny selection?

2) Ensure the popover window is the size that I created it with in the XIB file (currently, it resizes and removes some of the rightmost size of the window)

Thanks
tony

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To present it with no arrows pass 0 for "permittedArrowDirections":

```
[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

To center it, pass a 1x1 rect located at the center of your view:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(viewWidth/2, viewHeight/2, 1, 1);
[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

Then you have a centered and arrow-free popover.

The bit about removing the arrow could break at any time.  They didn't provide a UIPopoverArrowDirectionNone option for a reason, they may choose to throw an exception in the future when 0 is passed, or default to something.  Use it at your own risk.

Comment: For iPad in Landscape mode, I had to switch the CGRectMake width and height to get things centered correctly.

Comment: Works in iOS 7.0.x also.

Comment: In swift use UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros to remove the arrow

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UIPopoverController, it will have an arrow.  Here are your choices.

```
UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  
UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight
```

As you can see there is no UIPopoverArrowDirectionNone

As for the XIB size, in your ViewDidLoad Method of the implementation file, you can set the following.

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 360.0);
```

You can set the size any way you like for the popover.

Comment: yea but if you hardcode a 0 is like UIPopoverArrowDirectionNone

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working this one out but wanted to do as much in the storyboard as possible which changes the approach a bit:

1) Select the popover in the storyboard and un-tick Directions Up/Down/Left/Right to get rid of the arrows.

To center it on screen override prepare for segue and do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popover = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
    CGFloat horizontalInset = (self.view.frame.size.width - popover.popoverController.popoverContentSize.width) / (CGFloat)2.0;
    CGFloat verticalInset = (self.view.frame.size.height - popover.popoverController.popoverContentSize.height) / (CGFloat)2.0;
    popover.popoverController.popoverLayoutMargins =
        UIEdgeInsetsMake(
            verticalInset,
          horizontalInset,
            verticalInset,
          horizontalInset);
}
```

In my case I also found that the popover segue's corner radius didn't match my design so I change the background color to clear to sort that out i.e. add this to the above block:

```
popover.popoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

2) In the destination controller for the segue find the attribute 'Popover' and tick 'Use Explicit Size' and put the size of you want it to appear in popover mode.